# Vietnam Language encoding issue in ipad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, url-encoding

We are facing weird issue only in ipad safari browser.
When page is rendering with URL ex : /sản-phẩm/loại/chất-lỏng/ariel-power-gel 
It renders with encoded value : /vi-vn/sa%cc%89n-ph%c3%a2%cc%89m/loa%cc%a3i/ch%c3%a2%cc%81t-lo%cc%89ng/ariel-power-gel

And when you render the same URL by clicking 'GO' button of ipad. page renders with encoded value : /vi-vn/s%E1%BA%A3n-ph%E1%BA%A9m/lo%E1%BA%A1i/ch%E1%BA%A5t-l%E1%BB%8Fng/ariel-power-gel

which different from first encoded URL value. Because of this different encoding our application is not able to find correct file to render when click on 'GO'  button hence resulting 404 page.

Does any one faced this issue? Please help us.

Comment: I'm sorry for stupid question, but are you using UrlEncode and UrlDecode?

Comment: Hi Khazratbek.. No questions are stupid questions :). ya We are using UrlDecode for decoding incoming request..